# flutter SDK is not available in android studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I'm trying to run `Flutter` on Android studio but I have an issue resolving this error.
I'm using last version of every thing (like as dart and flutter or plugins).

> Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`

Comment: Did you install flutter plugin on android studio? Did you set the flutter sdk path?

Comment: We need more details. Like your extensions, and a reproduction repository.

Comment: @RémiRousselet and  I solved my problem by using the first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `local.properties` and edit it with error quick fix. I had same issue by adding one more backslash to path of flutter sdk.

Comment: Where to find this file ??

Comment: @TSR yourProjectName/android/local.properties

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this issue by providing the Flutter SDK path at:

*Settings > Language & Frameworks > Flutter*

[image]