# `The Flutter SDK is not available` when running `dart run ffigen`

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi

I'm trying to run `dart run ffigen` but I'm getting this error

```sh
$ dart run ffigen
The Flutter SDK is not available.
#0      BoundSdkSource.getDirectory (package:pub/src/source/sdk.dart:125:7)
#1      SystemCache.load (package:pub/src/system_cache.dart:113:52)
#2      Entrypoint._assertLockFileUpToDate (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:599:19)
#3      Entrypoint.assertUpToDate (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:525:7)
#4      getExecutableForCommand (package:pub/src/executable.dart:304:16)
#5      RunCommand.run (package:dartdev/src/commands/run.dart:232:32)
#6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:27)
#7      DartdevRunner.runCommand (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:232:30)
#8      CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:119:25)
#9      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:296:31)
#10     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:119:14)
#11     runDartdev (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:67:29)
#12     main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart:11:9)
#13     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:293:32)
#14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

do I have to set some environment variable to let Dart find the Flutter SDK? On the other hand, flutter finds the dart sdk without problems, as `flutter doctor -v` outputs

```sh
[  +44 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[   +4 ms] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] db747aa1331bd95bc9b3874c842261ca2d302cd5
[        ] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git tag --points-at db747aa1331bd95bc9b3874c842261ca2d302cd5
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at db747aa1331bd95bc9b3874c842261ca2d302cd5
[        ] 2.10.1
[   +7 ms] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +38 ms] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +34 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +28 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +72 ms] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[        ] Skipping request to fetchTags - on well known channel stable.
[        ] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[        ] 2.10.1
[   +7 ms] executing: /nix/store/rwkxxmjkyky2a8cvj0dk4qfdyyi1bxza-android-studio-beta-2021.2.1.8-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[  +78 ms] Exit code 0 from: /nix/store/rwkxxmjkyky2a8cvj0dk4qfdyyi1bxza-android-studio-beta-2021.2.1.8-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: /nix/store/cqzki4val7cgiazfxin930k5gr4aib2n-android-studio-beta-2021.1.1.18-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[  +60 ms] Exit code 0 from: /nix/store/cqzki4val7cgiazfxin930k5gr4aib2n-android-studio-beta-2021.1.1.18-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822, mixed mode)
[   +6 ms] executing: /nix/store/rwkxxmjkyky2a8cvj0dk4qfdyyi1bxza-android-studio-beta-2021.2.1.8-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[  +65 ms] Exit code 0 from: /nix/store/rwkxxmjkyky2a8cvj0dk4qfdyyi1bxza-android-studio-beta-2021.2.1.8-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840, mixed mode)
[        ] executing: /nix/store/cqzki4val7cgiazfxin930k5gr4aib2n-android-studio-beta-2021.1.1.18-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[  +61 ms] Exit code 0 from: /nix/store/cqzki4val7cgiazfxin930k5gr4aib2n-android-studio-beta-2021.1.1.18-unwrapped/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822, mixed mode)
[   +8 ms] executing: [/nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 5 weeks ago
[  +19 ms] java -version
[   +9 ms] executing: /nix/store/lfg1wh9ckm0l8q9dykgi7mfxjb1qx8ag-android-sdk-env/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +15 ms] [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on NixOS 22.05 (Quokka) 5.10.101, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[        ]     • Flutter version 2.10.1 at /nix/store/lmja0xh3y2plnks22mg5v6cmd2w7rxjh-flutter-2.10.1-unwrapped
[        ]     • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ]     • Framework revision db747aa133 (5 weeks ago), 2022-02-09 13:57:35 -0600
[        ]     • Engine revision ab46186b24
[        ]     • Dart version 2.16.1
[        ]     • DevTools version 2.9.2
[  +30 ms] List of devices attached
           af5bf12d               device usb:1-1 product:Nord_EEA model:AC2003 device:Nord transport_id:4
[   +7 ms] /nix/store/lfg1wh9ckm0l8q9dykgi7mfxjb1qx8ag-android-sdk-env/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s af5bf12d shell getprop
[  +49 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[   +2 ms] executing: /nix/store/lfg1wh9ckm0l8q9dykgi7mfxjb1qx8ag-android-sdk-env/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +13 ms] List of devices attached
           af5bf12d               device usb:1-1 product:Nord_EEA model:AC2003 device:Nord transport_id:4
[ +144 ms] [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[        ]     • Android SDK at /nix/store/lfg1wh9ckm0l8q9dykgi7mfxjb1qx8ag-android-sdk-env/share/android-sdk
[        ]     • Platform android-32, build-tools 30.0.2
[        ]     • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /nix/store/lfg1wh9ckm0l8q9dykgi7mfxjb1qx8ag-android-sdk-env/share/android-sdk
[        ]     • Java binary at: /nix/store/rwkxxmjkyky2a8cvj0dk4qfdyyi1bxza-android-studio-beta-2021.2.1.8-unwrapped/jre/bin/java
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
[        ]     ✗ Android license status unknown.
[        ]       Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
[        ]       See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[        ] [✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
[        ]     ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[        ] [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[        ]     • Android Studio at /nix/store/rwkxxmjkyky2a8cvj0dk4qfdyyi1bxza-android-studio-beta-2021.2.1.8-unwrapped
[        ]     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
[        ]     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
[        ] [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[        ]     • Android Studio at /nix/store/cqzki4val7cgiazfxin930k5gr4aib2n-android-studio-beta-2021.1.1.18-unwrapped
[        ]     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
[        ]     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
[        ] [✓] Connected device (1 available)
[        ]     • AC2003 (mobile) • af5bf12d • android-arm64 • Android 11 (API 30)
[+1209 ms] [✓] HTTP Host Availability
[        ]     • All required HTTP hosts are available
[        ] ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
[   +7 ms] "flutter doctor" took 1,940ms.
[  +64 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 61ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 0
```

Some more infos:

```sh
$ readlink -f (which flutter)
/nix/store/lw3dmab469hrqpwvmivjh2g56qi4ah59-flutter-2.10.1/bin/flutter
$ readlink -f (which dart)
/nix/store/nrabq29p4j14pxddmf6l8vc2z7zslzh8-dart-2.16.1/bin/dart
```

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048436/flutter-sdk-is-not-available-in-android-studio

Comment: Usually "The Flutter SDK is not available" means that you're running the `dart` command instead of the `flutter` command in a project that depends on the Flutter SDK.  Try `flutter run ffigen` instead.

Comment: just to add to @jamesdlin I think it would be `flutter pub run ffigen` in this case

Answer (score -1):

It's in `flutter doctor`:

accept licences and install chrome

```
✗ Android license status unknown.
[        ]       Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
[        ]       See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[        ] [✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
[        ]     ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
```